# How principal works when restrictingS 3 access by bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently my S3 policy is like this below.

What I want to do is restrict read/write S3 access from a lambda. And enable public read access to S3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-static-resource-v/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::678100228133:role/vr-resource-CustomS3AutoDeleteObjectsCustomRes-1H51E87NWQJ81"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-static-resource-v",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-static-resource-v/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess I should add the lambda arn in `Principal`,

so I changed,

```
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
```

to lambda arn, but

```
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:67810022843r:function:vr-dev-lambda"
        },
```

but it shows

`Invalid principal in policy`

How can I set here?

Comment: Ideally, the Lambda function's IAM role would have the relevant permissions in its IAM policies and you would not attempt to do this in an S3 bucket policy. Also, potential typo: `67810022843r`.

Comment: You should put the permissions directly on the IAM Role used by the Lambda function, rather than the Bucket Policy. While it is possible to do it via a Bucket Policy, it is not a scalable option due to limits in the policy size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambdas have an execution roles attached to them. For example:

[image]

If you want to limit the S3 access to your Lambda, you would want to specify the ARN of this execution role.

[image]